# taking input from Thymeleaf via radio buttons, returning a List in a wrapper object to the controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to take input from user via radio buttons in Thymeleaf. And I am updating a List via a wrapper from that input. But I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.

```
public class ShiftDto {

    private String fullName;
    private int shiftCode;

    public ShiftDto(String fullName, int shiftCode) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.shiftCode = shiftCode;
    }
}


public class DtoWrapper {
    private List<ShiftDto> shifts;
}

@PostMapping("/upload")
    public String upload(Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        if (ReadXlsxService.hasExcelFormat(file)) {
            try {
                model.addAttribute("msg", "Successfully Uploaded: " + file.getOriginalFilename());

                allSwipes = ReadXlsxService.readAllRows(file.getInputStream());
                Set<Officer> officers = ExtractOfficers.from(allSwipes);
                List<ShiftDto> shiftDtos = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Officer officer : officers) {
                    shiftDtos.add(new ShiftDto(officer.toString(), 0));
                }
                DtoWrapper dtoWrapper = new DtoWrapper();
                dtoWrapper.setShifts(shiftDtos);
                model.addAttribute("dtoWrapper", dtoWrapper);
                return "shift-info";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                model.addAttribute("msg", "Uploaded file is not in expected format");
            }
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "The uploaded file is not a xlsx file");
        }
        return "failedUploadView";
    }

@GetMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> download(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Controller.download");
    try {
        String filename = createFileName();
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "force-download"));
        header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        List<Shift> shifts = getShifts(model);
        List<OutputRow> outputData = SwipeProcessor.getOutputDataFrom(allSwipes, shifts);
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(WriteOutputToXlsx.write(outputData));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, header, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Excel Parsing Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <span th:text="${msg}"></span>
    <h2>Enter shift information</h2>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/download}" th:object="${dtoWrapper}" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select Shift information for each officer</legend>
            <ul>
                <li th:each="shiftDto : ${dtoWrapper.getShifts()}">
                    <span th:text="${shiftDto.getFullName()}"></span>
                    <input type="radio" id="ignore" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="0" checked>
                    <label for="ignore">Ignore</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="mgDay" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="1">
                    <label for="mgDay">MG Day</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="mgNight" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="2">
                    <label for="mgNight">MG Night</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="epWbDay" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="3">
                    <label for="epWbDay">EP WB Day</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="epWbNight" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="4">
                    <label for="epWbNight">EP WB Night</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" id="visRecep" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="5">
                    <label for="visRecep">Visitors Recep</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="plDay" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="6">
                    <label for="plDay">Plaistow Day</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="plNight" name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}" value="7">
                    <label for="plNight">Plaistow Night</label>
                    <br><br>
                    <!--                    <span th:text="${officer}"></span>-->
                </li>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: My output screen]

1. Currently all the radio buttons are behaving as one group. How can I group them separately for each name.
2. How to get the radio button value into dtoWrapper object.
3. How to access wrapper from /download controller model argument

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are missing a couple of Thymeleaf-related items in your template.

First of all, the `name` attribute:

```
name="${shiftDto.getFullName()}"
```

This should be:

```
th:name="${shiftDto.fullName}"
```

I added `th:` to the `name` attribute to cause it to be processed by Thymeleaf (otherwise it is ignored by Thymeleaf). If Thymeleaf ignores the attribute, all your names are the same - they are all *exactly* the following string: `${shiftDto.getFullName()}` - and this is why there is no grouping of radio buttons by name.

Note also that I changed `getFullName()` to simply `fullName`. As long as your Java class has a suitable getter (`getFullName()`), which matches the related field (`fullName`), then the Thymeleaf expression can use the field name. This simplifies your templates: you can use the Java field names, instead of the Java method names.

Next change:

I changed the `id` attribute so that every ID will be unique (a page should never contain duplicate ID attributes).

```
th:id="'ignore_' + ${iterStat.count}"
```

The `iterStat` value is just a way to provide an iteration counter in Thymeleaf. See [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#keeping-iteration-status) for details.

You can choose to use any value you wish, as long as the end result that every id is unique in the page.

The full code is as follows:

```
<form ... >
    <ul>
        <li th:each="shiftDto,iterStat : ${dtoWrapper.getShifts()}">
            <span th:text="${shiftDto.fullName}"></span>
            <input type="radio" th:id="'ignore_' + ${iterStat.count}" th:name="${shiftDto.fullName}" value="0" checked>
            <label for="ignore">Ignore</label>
            <input type="radio" th:id="'mgDay' + ${iterStat.count}" th:name="${shiftDto.fullName}" value="0" checked>
            <label for="ignore">MG Day</label>
            <input type="radio" th:id="'mgNight' + ${iterStat.count}" th:name="${shiftDto.fullName}" value="0" checked>
            <label for="ignore">MG Night</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

(I have not shown all your fields or names here, for brevity.)

When you select some values, you will now see that the radio buttons are in independent groups.

---

Form submission:

When you submit the form data, you will see a response payload similar to this:

```
Alan+Smith=0&Brian+Jones=1&Charles+Worth=2
```

This corresponds to the following selections in the form:

[image]

---

It can also be helpful to see how the Thymeleaf template is converted to HTML. Here is my HTML for the above code:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Alan Smith</span>
        <input type="radio" id="ignore_1" name="Alan Smith" value="0" checked>
        <label for="ignore">Ignore</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mgDay1" name="Alan Smith" value="1" checked>
        <label for="ignore">MG Day</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mgNight1" name="Alan Smith" value="2" checked>
        <label for="ignore">MG Night</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Brian Jones</span>
        <input type="radio" id="ignore_2" name="Brian Jones" value="0" checked>
        <label for="ignore">Ignore</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mgDay2" name="Brian Jones" value="1" checked>
        <label for="ignore">MG Day</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mgNight2" name="Brian Jones" value="2" checked>
        <label for="ignore">MG Night</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Charles Worth</span>
        <input type="radio" id="ignore_3" name="Charles Worth" value="0" checked>
        <label for="ignore">Ignore</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mgDay3" name="Charles Worth" value="1" checked>
        <label for="ignore">MG Day</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mgNight3" name="Charles Worth" value="2" checked>
        <label for="ignore">MG Night</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```